# Best way to execute AppleScript from Java

Tags: java, macos, applescript, execution-time

I have a couple of AppleScripts that i want to run from Java. I have several options including:

Running the AppleScript as a string using the AppleScript ScriptEngine (using `((new ScriptEngineManager()).getEngineByName("AppleScript")).eval(scriptString))`)

Saving the AppleScript as an Application and running the app from Java (using `Desktop.getDesktop().open("name.app")`)

Those two seemed the best options to me and I was wondering

Is there a better way?

If !(1.) Which of these two ways is the best? (Speedwise)

If !(1.) Are there ways to improve my methods?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I would go with 2, that seems like a very big hammer.

The other old style solution was to exec 'osascript' command.

As far as I know using the script engine support is the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

Your first option sounds right to me, but if for some reason you want to run it as an external script, you could consider running an osascript the same way you would run a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that option 1 might be your best bet, because of how Applescript works.

There are two types of Applescript: plain text Applescript, then compiled Applescript. Complied Applescript has been translated (essentially) into bytecode by the Applescript complier.

Thus, if your application allows it, you may consider compiling all your Applescripts *once*, then calling them later. This will save you some time (seconds?).

(I'm just guessing here that, in addition to the `eval` command, your Java class has a way to just compile Applescript.)

During the compilation stage, Applescript also tries to identify all the applications the script uses. I believe it's during this phase where Applescript might say, "I'm sorry, I can't find SurfWriter, please point me to the app". This kind of user experience is one of those things the user wants to do as little as possible ;)